# understanding project directory in Python outside Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been struggeling with the project directory in Python.

I have a project in Pycharm that works perfect, but when I want to execute the same project from commandline, I have some issues.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
[project dir]/projectController/
[project dir]/projectLib/
[project dir]/projectWeb/
```

I'm using an virtual environment.

When I want to request a function from projectLib

```py
from projectLib.utils import *
```

When I execute this in Pycharm, it works just fine. But when I execute:

```
venv/bin/python projectWeb/run.py
```

I get the following error:

```
No module named 'projectLib'
```

I tried to add the path by code

```
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
```

But this doesn't solve the problem neither. What am I missing here?

Here's my Pycharm config:
[image]

Working directory is equal to [project dir]
Script path is equal to [project dir]/projectWeb/run.py

Comment: Where did you put the `sys.path.insert`? Try printing `sys.path` at the top of run.py, and compare the output from within PyCharm and when you run it from virtualenv.

Comment: 1) You should activate your venv not execute the intepreter, 2) You should be able to solve parallel folder structure with `sys.insert()` but maybe a different error occured. So, provide the actual code, the location of module being called etc

Comment: Can you  also provide a screenshot of the "configuration" window in PyCharm when running it from there, which will tells us `scipt path` and `working directory`

Comment: If you are using `sys.path.insert` you are almost certainly doing something wrong. I never needed to do that and certainly a new user of python need not do any fancy thing that requires its use. One suggestion I can give you is to separate the "dev environment" from the "production environment". For the latter you should create a package to be installed via `pip` or similar and "do everything proper for a proper installation". For development use the virtual env. Sometimes using `pip install --editable` is fine.

Comment: I've managed to get it working by adding the following to sys.path. 
    `BASE_FOLDER = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.insert(0, BASE_FOLDER) ` Is solves my problem I see. But is this the way?